# objects in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Im adding objects to a datagridview ( only one kind) through a list
ej.

```
List<Material> mater = new List<Material>();
DataGridView dgvMAterial = new DataGridView();

dgvMaterial.DataSource = null;
mater.Add((Material)cmbMaterial.SelectedValue);
dgvMaterial.DataSource = mater;
```

But every time I click over the datagrid I get an indexoutofrangeexeption.
Can somone tell me why?
thanks

here is my whole code for the form

```
public partial class inicio : Form
{
    private string ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=data.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    //private string ConnectionString = "Server=.\\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\data\\data_data.mdf.mdf; Database=data.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
    private ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
    List<Material> mater = new List<Material>();
    List<Salarios> salar = new List<Salarios>();
    IBindingList mind = new BindingList<Salarios>();
    Productos prod;

    public inicio()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sessionFactory = nhn.BusinessObjects.Initialize.CreateSessionFactory(ConnectionString);
        dgvMaterial.DataSource = mater;
    }

    private void materialToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Catalogos.frmMaterial material = new costeos.Catalogos.frmMaterial(ConnectionString);
        material.ShowDialog(this);
        material.Dispose();
    }

    private void salariosToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Catalogos.frmSalarios salarios = new costeos.Catalogos.frmSalarios(ConnectionString);
        salarios.ShowDialog(this);
        salarios.Dispose();
    }

    private void agregarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Catalogos.frmAddRemuneraciones rem = new costeos.Catalogos.frmAddRemuneraciones(ConnectionString);
        rem.ShowDialog(this);
        rem.Dispose();
    }

    private void agregarToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Catalogos.frmAddAdmin adm = new costeos.Catalogos.frmAddAdmin(ConnectionString);
        adm.ShowDialog(this);
        adm.Dispose();
    }

    private void agregarToolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Catalogos.frmAddInsumosInd insumos = new costeos.Catalogos.frmAddInsumosInd(ConnectionString);
        insumos.ShowDialog(this);
        insumos.Dispose();
    }

    private void txt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar) || char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void inicio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LlenaCampos();
    }

    private void LlenaCampos()
    {
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var mat = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Material))
                    .List<Material>();
                var sal = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Salarios))
                    .List<Salarios>();
                transaction.Commit();

                cmbMaterial.DataSource = mat;
                cmbMaterial.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
                cmbSalarios.DataSource = sal;
                cmbSalarios.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
                cmbMIndirecta.DataSource = sal;
                cmbMIndirecta.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnAddMaterial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        materialBindingSource.DataSource = null;
        //dgvMaterial.DataSource = null;
        mater.Add((Material)cmbMaterial.SelectedValue);
        //dgvMaterial.DataSource = mater;
        dgvMaterial.DataSource = materialBindingSource;
        materialBindingSource.DataSource = mater;
        materialBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvSalarios.DataSource = null;
        salar.Add((Salarios)cmbSalarios.SelectedValue);
        dgvSalarios.DataSource = salar;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        dgvMIndirecta.DataSource = null;
        mind.Add((Salarios)cmbMIndirecta.SelectedValue);
        dgvMIndirecta.DataSource = mind;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                if (prod == null)
                {
                    prod = new Productos { CargasTurno = float.Parse(txtCargasTurno.Text), CavidadesMolde = int.Parse(txtCavidadesMolde.Text), Clave = txtClave.Text, Comentarios = txtComentarios.Text, MezclasTurno = float.Parse(txtMezclasTurno.Text), Moldes = int.Parse(txtMoldes.Text), Nombre = txtNombre.Text, Peso = float.Parse(txtPesoTotal.Text), TotalPza = int.Parse(txtPzasTotales.Text), Turnos = int.Parse(txtTurnos.Text) };
                    session.Save(prod);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvMaterial.Rows)
                {
                    Material m = dr.DataBoundItem as Material;
                    m.Materiales 
                    PMaterial mat = new PMaterial { Material = dr.DataBoundItem as Material, Cantidad = float.Parse(dr.Cells["Cantidad"].Value.ToString()), Fecha = DateTime.Now, Producto = prod };
                    session.Save(mat);
                }
                transaction.Commit();
                session.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you creating a new grid every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would *guess* that you have an event-handler that isn't happy. What *exactly* does the message say?

You might *also* be having problems if you are adding the **same** `Material` instance to the list multiple times; since `IndexOf` will only find the **first** occurrence. This line makes me very suspicious:

```
mater.Add((Material)cmbMaterial.SelectedValue);
```

since it could potentially (on consecutive clicks / etc) do exactly this.

---

Note: if you used `BindingList<T>` instead all you'd have to doo is `Add(...)` - no resetting required:

field:

```
BindingList<Material> mater = new BindingList<Material>();
```

init grid:

```
dgvMaterial.DataSource = mater;
```

add item:

```
mater.Add(newInstance);
```

Comment: Thanks to all I've changed it to use a BindingList and it worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's probably not DGV problem, but with this combo box. Show us the code that fills combo box and sets its properties.

If you are casting to Material class you should probably use SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue. (unless you exactly know what you're doing)

Answer (score 0):

If you assign data source to the DGV you should check element count - if zero then assign null. I don't know why this is the way it is, but I'm doing it in all my forms.

//I'm still analysing the rest of the code